# Google Maps Polyline using Google Maps Directions Service

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Rigth now on my app I generate a polyline in this way, I receive an array "route" with all markers that I get from database with that markers it´s possible to generate the polyline:

```
var routeArray = null;
function drawRoute(mapa, routeArray, varBool){
    if(!routeArray){
        var coordRoute = routeArray;
        routeArray= new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map,
            path: coordRoute,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3
        });
    }if(varBool){
        routeArray.setMap(map);
    }else{
        routeArray.setMap(null);
    }
}
```

I would like to generate the polyline, but instead this way in which you see straigth lines I would prefer Google Directions Service. Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [the google direction api docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) for usage info and examples? Have you tried anything? Please do so and if you have questions/issues post your new code and we can help further.

Comment: I´m working with that API, I have some code, maybe I´ve abussed "little bit", thanks for your advice.